# How to run several separate Wordpress websites using Docker containers

Tags: wordpress, docker

I am very new to Docker, and am currently attempting to run a Wordpress website (just on my local machine for testing purposes--not actually hosting). I currently have three containers: One linux distribution to store my data, used by a MySQL container, and finally a Wordpress container.

I can successfully access and edit my Wordpress website, but I would like to try and run multiple websites on different ports, and am unsure how to do so. Would I have to create three brand new containers, or could I use the same MySQL and datastore containers and simply make a different wordpress container?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using official Wordpress image, you can use the same MySQL container. Just provide different database for each Wordpress container. You can define database for Wordpress container with environment variables, for example:

`docker run --name wordpress1 --link some-mysql:mysql -p 8080:80 -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress1 -d wordpress`

`docker run --name wordpress2 --link some-mysql:mysql -p 8081:80 -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress2 -d wordpress`

`docker run --name wordpress3 --link some-mysql:mysql -p 8082:80 -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress3 -d wordpress`

Answer (score 0):

So long as they use the same db, or the same db server at least (which btw don't put your database in a container, a database writes to disk and defeats the purpose of using a container, unless that container will never change location), you'd be best off creating new wordpress containers for each, they can share layers of the containers, so 3 wordpress containers won't be too large, the only different layer would be the site's code, so that's your best bet.

Comment: Why do you believe that a database inside a container defeats the purpose of using a container? From my understanding it is one of the key reasons to use containers at all. In combination with a data-only container providing the storage for the mysql-server it is one of the most portable solutions I can think of. See for example the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container), which even has a container hosting a database as its core example.

Comment: I believe so because the file system in a container (default fs I'm talking about) are ephemeral.  There for if PID 1 of that container, which chances are it's the DB daemon process, the data stored will be lost.  Additionally you can't guarantee the DB container(s) can always be on the same host unless you have only one host for the DB container.  Flocker, and a few other tools do a good job of fixing these issues, but a stand alone container does not account for this.